# FLUSH_REWRITE_RULES - after or before REGISTER_POST_TYPE?

Tags: rewrite-rules

I know that `flush_rewrite_rules()` should be called only on plugin activation (or on major events, not on every pageload). But it's recommended to call after I execute `register_post_type()` or before it ?

Answer (score 3):

Flushing rules forces them to be rebuilt from whatever is currently registered, so you should register post types before flushing.

This is why you must register your post types in a plugin activation hook as well as on init, otherwise your rules won’t exist on subsequent requests if you’re flushing on activation.

Comment: ?? really? but everywhere is said to flush only after changing permalinks (so, once in a while), not on every init.... why do you say that?

Comment: I didn’t say on every init. You asked if the post types need to be registered before or after a flush, and the answer is before.